# Sonar-Runner cannot connect to Oracle EX

Tags: oracle, connection, localhost, sonar-runner

I executed

```
sonar-runner -e
```

but the message `EXECUTION FAILURE` is displayed.

> Caused by:org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost"

I can see local Sonar Web, but I can't analize code because JDBC connection fails.

I've installed Oracle Express in my PC.

In sonar.properties I uncomment this line:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE
```

In `sonar-runner.properties` I write this line:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:9000
```

Thank you very much :)

Dani

Answer (score 0):

Both declarations should be the same in both files.

localhost:9000 is the SonarQube webpage so you sonar-runner.properties is not correct. Replace it with what you have in the sonar.properties.